# Is there a license to make your code open source, but at the same time for people not to be able to use the code?

Tags: license-recommendation, license

I'm trying to make an app, and I'm actually serious about it. I'm using electron, so I know my source code is guaranteed to be leaked. I was thinking of making my app open source, but at the same time I don't want someone to steal it and republish it. Is there some sort of license preventing people from using my code, but at the same time keep my app open source?

Comment: The license you are describing is not [open source as defined by this site](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), so is off-topic.

Comment: If by *open source* you don't mean *free for use by anyone for any purpose*, what do you mean by it?

Comment: No license allows misrepresenting authorship. No license, proprietary or not, will stop malicious people from doing so, though

Comment: I dont actually want my project to be open source. But because im making it with electron its source code is guaranteed to be leaked. What I want is a license that will not allow people to use my code.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is (now) explicitly not about Open Source within the remit of the site.

Answer (score 2):

A corner stone of open-source licensing is that anyone and everyone is allowed to redistribute or republish the work.

If you don't want that, then you must not use an open-source license.

To protect your project from re-publication, any license that does not allow redistribution is sufficient, or even no license at all. It does not matter if people can obtain your source code or not, it matters what they are allowed to do with it.